# How do I prevent the user to change the shipping address? Or instant update callback for Payflow Pro Express Checkout

Tags: paypal

I'm using Payflowlink Pro Express Checkout

Flow:

1. User select items on merchant site.
2. User clicks buy and fill shipping address.
3. Server get rates from USPS and FedEx for selected items.
4. User selects desired postal service with defined rate.
5. Server calls paypal to setup transaction with selected shipping rate.
6. User on paypal where he or she able to change shipping address, but shipping rate is already calculated for address what he inputted on merchant site.

I've found a solution of my problem only for classic API (Instant update callback), but not for Payflow Pro Express Checkout

Like a part of solution, user'll be warned about this situation on merchant site, but.. How do I prevent the PP user to change the shipping address or tell me please if it is possible to use instant update callback for Payflow Pro Express Checkout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `ADDROVERIDE` variable with a value of `1`. Doing that tells PayPal to use the shipping address you provided and not the address the buyer has set in their PayPal account.

The `ADDROVERIDE` and the shipping variables are available in the Express Checkout for Payflow Pro guide.

Comment: I've added NOSHIPPING=1 and ADDROVERIDE=1 to my request and I've get a desired result. Thanks!

Comment: Documented I see a value called ADDRESSOVERRIDE but nothing called ADDROVERIDE. The NOSHIPPING does seem to remove any address stuff at all though.

Comment: it is depends on the version of paypal.api you are using. will write here what version i was using when will find it.

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry, I wanted to add this as a comment to the above, but my reputation is < 50**

For some reason I couldn't get NOSHIPPING=1 and ADDROVERIDE=1 to prevent paypal asking for the shipping address; It may be due to me not supplying the address to PayPal in the first place.

However, 'no_shipping=1' does prevents PayPal asking the user for the shipping address (for me at least)

I think there may be two different solutions based on certain scenarios, so if one is not working try the other.